# Making a shape in processing

Tags: java, processing

I was working on an animation on processing. Then, I have a question about the code. Normally, my code is more long. However, I made a simple code which can usefull also for the beginners. My sample code:

```
 void setup() {
  size(250, 250);
}

void draw() {
  background(102);
  translate(100, 100);
  beginShape();
  vertex(0,0);
  vertex(-50, 50);
  vertex(0, 100);
  endShape();
}
```

I have to use three vertexes and I want to texture the Shape as in `texture()`. How to make that?

Comment: Hi Daymnn, can you be more specific please? 1) Are you talking about a rectangle or about a triangle? 2) Do you want to _texture_ the Shape as in [texture()](https://processing.org/reference/texture_.html) or do you want to fill/stroke... the Shape?

Comment: Hi, Laos, Yes I edited the question. I'm talking about the shape of triangle. Also, I want to texture the Shape as in `texture()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to put an image as a texture on a Shape:

1. Use a P2D or a P3D render, instead of the default render.
2. Load the image which is going to texture your Shape.
3. Call the `texture()` function when you begin to set up the Shape.
4. Establish the *mode* (IMAGE) and the *wrap* (CLAMP) for the texture image.
5. Choose three points of the image as the vertices for the triangle. For example `(0, 0)`, `(0, img.height)` and `(img.width, img.height)`.

```
PImage img;

void setup() {
  size(250, 250, P2D);
  img = loadImage("rectangular_image.jpg");
  textureMode(IMAGE);
  textureWrap(CLAMP);
}

void draw() {
  background(102);
  translate(100, 100);
  noStroke();
  beginShape();
  texture(img);
  vertex(0, 0, 0, 0);
  vertex(-50, 50, 0, img.height);
  vertex(0, 100, img.width, img.height);
  endShape();
}
```